# Playing video on PEPPER's tablet using Choregraphe

Tags: nao-robot, pepper, choregraphe

Whenever I try to play a video (on PEPPERS tablet), that is locally saved, I encounter the following problem - on the PEPPER's tablet the error message "Video could not be played" is displayed. I am using Choregraphe and its standard 'play video' box.

Here is a screenshot of the project

**EDITED**
[image: Capture of the project in Choregraphe]

I think the problem may occur because:

1. The path to the video is not set correctly, but I highly doubt this is the case.
2. The video formats I have tested are mp4 and mov, that are converted from random youtube videos.

So my question is why the video can not be played on the PEPPER's tablet this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with just the name my_video.mp4 as parameter, no quote or "/".

Recommended format is mp4 container, video codec H.264, audio codec AAC...

Also, disconnect the output, otherwise as soon as you video starts, it will be required to stop ;-)